# Stock camera app missing and front camera reported as rear camera in XOLO Q1000s

Tags: camera

I bought a new XOLO Q1000s recently, and I made sure to test the back camera before buying it. After four or five days, when I tried to use the camera for the first time, it shows only the front camera; there is no option anywhere to shift to the back camera.

I tried installing other camera apps to get the back camera, but that didn't work. I then did a factory reset, but after that, the camera app itself went missing.

My phone is not rooted, but I no longer have a built-in camera app. I can install other camera apps, but they only show the front camera. When I tried to shift the camera in the camera app, it said you have no front camera! And yet it shows the front camera and doesn't use the back one. Similarly, when trying a flashlight app, it says I have no flashlight, even though my mobile has one.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think it is a hardware issue. I have had issues like that and never knew what the problem was until one day I had a broken screen and took the phone to the repairer. After changing the screen, I realised that the rear camera wasn't working (I've never had a problem with the camera on that device). I took the phone back to him and he just re-adjusted the camera cords or something else (I don't know the technical term for cables) and it was working just fine.